# Проблема в реализации метода простых итераций для решения нелинейных уравнений

Tags: c++, математика

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: реализуя метод простых итераций для решения нелинейных уравнений для функции x^2 + x + 4cos x − 4.1 = 0, у меня решение выходит за пределы задаваемого отрезка. Вероятно, проблема в реализации моего метода. Можете помочь обнаружить ошибку? К примеру, на отрезке [1; 1.5] должен быть корень данного уравнения, однако программа находит корень уравнения, не удовлетворяющему этому отрезку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

double f(double x) //возвращает значение функции f(x) = x^2-2
{
    return x * x + x + 4 * cos(x) - 4.1;
}

double phi(double x)
{
    return 4.1 - 4 * cos(x) - x * x;
}


void iterations(double eps)
{
    int exit = 0, i = 0;//переменные для выхода и цикла
    double x0, x1;
    double a, b;
    do
    {
        i = 0;
        cout << "Please input [a;b]\n=>";
        cin >> a >> b; // вводим границы отрезка, на котором будем искать корень
        if (f(a) * f(b) > 0) // если знаки функции на краях отрезка одинаковые, то здесь нет корня
            cout << "\nError! No roots in this interval\n";
        else
        {
            x0 = (a + b) / 2;
            do
            {
                x1 = x0;
                x0 = phi(x1);
                cout << ++i << "-th iteration = " << x0 << "\n";
            } while (fabs(x0 - x1) > eps);
            printf("Root = %.15lf", x0);
        }
        cout << "\nExit?=>";
        cin >> exit;
    } while (exit != 1); // пока пользователь не ввел exit = 1
}
int main()
{
    double eps = pow(10, -10);
    iterations(eps);
}
```

Comment: Поясняю: для метода простых итераций  мы представляем исходное уравнение в виде x = phi(x), поэтому я отдельно прописал функцию phi(x) как 4.1 - 4 * cos(x) - x * x

Comment: "К примеру, на отрезке [1; 1.5] должен быть корень данного уравнения" - какой? "однако программа находит корень уравнения" - какой?

Comment: Точно, конечно, сказать не могу, что это за корень, но приблизительно он равен 1.1686 (тот корень, который по-хорошему должна была найти моя программа), а находит она значение приблизительно 1.7509 (это тоже корень данного уравнения, но он очевидно не принадлежит указанному в моём вопросе отрезку).

Comment: Ну, обычно в качестве  `phi(x)` берут следующую штуку: `phi(x) := x - lambda * f(x)`. Причём знак константы `lambda` должен совпадать со знаком производной в окрестности корня. Вы взяли `lambda == 1`, и производная функции `f(x)` в окрестности корня `1.7509` как раз положительна, поэтому к этому корню метод и сходится. В окрестности же корня `1.1686` производная `f(x)` отрицательна, поэтому попробуйте взять `lambda == -1`, тогда `phi(x)` примет вид: `phi(x) := 2*x + x*x + 4*cos(x) - 4.1`.

Comment: Есть еще очень большой и важный вопрос о сходимости этого метода. Его нельзя применять просто так. "Война — это не покер, ее нельзя объявлять, когда вздумается!" (с)

Comment: @wololo, спасибо большое! А если в окрестности корня производная принимает как положительные, так и отрицательные значения?

Comment: И у меня ещё один вопрос. А что делать в случае отрезка [-3.5; -3] ? Дело в том, что там тоже в окрестности корня производная отрицательная, и запуская свою программу, у меня выдаёт значение 1.16856...

Comment: У метода есть определённые [условия сходимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). В частности, если в окрестности корня производная принимает как положительные, так и отрицательные значения, то нарушается условие `lambda * f'(x) > 0`, следовательно сходимость не гарантируется.

Comment: `А что делать в случае отрезка [-3.5; -3] ?` Опять же, необходимо проверить все ли необходимые условия выполнены.... Возможно, следует уменьшить абсолютное значение  `lambda` или ещё чего-нибудь подкорректировать... «Есть еще очень большой и важный вопрос о сходимости этого метода. Его нельзя применять просто так.» (с)

Comment: Ну, например, просто на вскидку взяв в вашей программе `a = -3.5; b = -3;` и `lambda = -0.1;` я получил в качестве корня значение `-3.371385...`, что похоже на правду...

Comment: Спасибо большое ещё раз!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы точно реализовывал fi для более общего случая, примерно так

```
double fi(double x, double K) {
    return  x + K*f(x);
}
```

и в цикле бы делал что то такое:

```
y = fi(x,K);
b = fabs(x - y);
x = y;
n += 1;
```

Comment: вероятно, я чего-то не понимаю, но как это связано с методом простых итераций? Для более общего случая phi, вообще говоря, невозможно написать, и я не совсем понимаю, что означает данный цикл.

Comment: Я не очень понял что вы делаете в цикле, по этому открыл свою старую реализацию из универа, которую я сдал, и попытался сравнить с тем что у вас сейчас